# Batch plot in GNUplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

Can anyone please help me with batch plotting in GNUplot? I have to plot around 20 of them. The file which contains the GNUplot commands, need to be changed only at two places to account for different filenames.

```
    set output "~/NEW1_line_hist_F1.eps"
    .
    .
    .
    .
    plot '~/performancePlotLineAndHist_F1.txt'   using 2: xtic(1) title column with histogram  , ''  using 3: xtic(1) title column with histogram
```

The files names vary from "...F1.txt" to "...F21.txt" and "...F1.eps" to "...F21.eps".

Is there a way I can automate the entire thing without having to manually update the 2 values manually and then run the code over and over again?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There sure is! You will want to use a do loop:

```
do for [ii=1:21] {
  set output 'F'.ii.'.eps'
  plot '~/performancePlotLineAndHist_F'.ii.'.txt' using ...
}
```

Side note: you may also want to store all those files in a place other than your home directory.